# Requirejs jQuery is overriding the jQuery loaded by wordpress, how can i avoid that (by calling noConflict( true) )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm using the jQuery version of require.js in my wordpress plugin but the jQuery from requirejs is overriding the jQuery loaded by wordpress. 
How can i tell the jQuery used by requirejs to call on itself `noConflict( true )` so that it doesn't override the version loaded by wordpress?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end i did things like this:

Create a config file like this

```
requirejs.config( {
    "paths": { 
        "jquery": "require_jquery"
    },
    "shim": {
        "jquery-cookie"  : ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap-tab"  : ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap-modal": ["jquery"],
        "bootstrap-alert": ["jquery"]
    }
} );
```

Create a require_jquery.js file like this

```
define(["jquery-1.7.2"], function() {
    // Raw jQuery does not return anything, so return it explicitly here.
    return jQuery.noConflict( true );
})
```

And then use jquery as normal. Everything works and the outside version of jQuery is untouched.

Comment: Question: does this mean tht two versions of jQuery are loaded onto the page?

Comment: @kaidez Yes, the idea is that there is one global version and one version which is just inside require.js. I use this in my wordpress plugin to avoid having to rely on Wordpress version of jQuery